# Junit with Mockito for java

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

I am learning java and exploring junit with Mockito.
The idea is to understand where and how to use mockito and learn how to write junit tests. Im a beginner and learning.

How can i write a junit test with mockito for the following code :

```
public class QueryBuilder<EntityT> {
private List<List<String>> allConditions;
private int top;
private int skip;
private FieldOrdering ordering;
private String tableName;

public QueryBuilder() {
    this.allConditions = new ArrayList<>();
    this.top = -1;
    this.skip = 0;
    this.ordering = new FieldOrdering();
    this.tableName = "your_table"; // Default table name
}

public QueryBuilder<EntityT> filter(FilterableExpression filters) {
    allConditions.add(filters.getConditions());
    return this;
}

public QueryBuilder<EntityT> and() {
    allConditions.get(allConditions.size() - 1).add(" AND ");
    return this;
}

public QueryBuilder<EntityT> or() {
    allConditions.get(allConditions.size() - 1).add(" OR ");
    return this;
}

public QueryBuilder<EntityT> top(int count) {
    this.top = count;
    return this;
}

public QueryBuilder<EntityT> skip(int count) {
    this.skip = count;
    return this;
}

public QueryBuilder<EntityT> orderBy(FieldOrdering ordering) {
    this.ordering = ordering;
    return this;
}

public QueryBuilder<EntityT> tableName(String tableName) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    return this;
}

/**
 * build the query with the clauses addded to Filter Expression *
 * 
 * @return
 */
public String build() {
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE ");

    if (!allConditions.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < allConditions.size(); i++) {
            List<String> conditions = allConditions.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < conditions.size(); j++) {
                query.append(conditions.get(j));
                if (j < conditions.size() - 1 && !conditions.get(j + 1).equals(" AND ")
                        && !conditions.get(j + 1).equals(" OR ")) {
                    query.append(" ");
                }
            }
            if (i < allConditions.size() - 1) {
                query.append(" AND ");
            }
        }
    } else {
        query.append("1=1");
    }

    List<String> orderByList = ordering.getOrderByList();
    if (!orderByList.isEmpty()) {
        query.append(" ORDER BY ").append(String.join(", ", orderByList));
    }

    if (top > 0) {
        query.append(" LIMIT ").append(top);
    }

    if (skip > 0) {
        query.append(" OFFSET ").append(skip);
    }

    return query.toString();
}
```

}

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated. I want to write the test, check the flow and understand how everything works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how you would need to mock anything for this. I'm not sure what the code is planned to do, but I'd be very surprised if you weren't better off with a `Map<String, SortDirection>`.

Comment: There are no types in this class that could be mocked or would benefit from mocking/stubbing. Just test it directly.

Comment: understood, thanks for ur inputs. I will update the question with the code that needs the output from these classes.

Comment: I still don't think anything needs to be stubbed here. Build your query using the builder, then compare it against your expectations. The only thing that _could_ be stubbed is `FilterableExpression`, but I doubt that's a type that's slow or difficult to construct with a lot of dependencies?

Comment: Not answering your question: It seems you are building an SQL query by joining strings. This is prone to SQL injection attacks. You should be using parametrized queries instead.

Comment: [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score -1):

UPD: It's just an illustration code here (use it like pattern for testing your logic):

```
@Mock
QueryBuilder queryBuilder;

@Test
void mockBuildMethodTest(){

  String predefined = "SOME PREDEFINED SQL";

  Mockito.doReturn(predefined)
    .when(queryBuilder)
    .build();

  Assertions.assertEquals(predefined, queryBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: That's a useless test, it doesn't test anything (short of verifying that Mockito itself works)

Comment: It's an illustration. @knittl

Comment: thanks @DimXenon, appreciate ur reply and the sample.